# Plotly - x axis created gap when plotting financial data

Tags: python, plotly

Im plotting a market breadth, my last bar chart in the images below as you can see there are some gap of the date the the stock market closed. However in my dataframe , those date weren't there, im not sure why it came up can anyone help me please.

Please help me find a way to remove the gap

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create TV Datafeed instance
tv = TvDatafeed()

# 1) Create Main CandleStick Chart
data_feed = tv.get_hist(symbol="SET", exchange='SET', interval=Interval.in_daily, n_bars=250)


# 6) Advance Decline Unchanged Chart
file_path_advance_decline_unchanged = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Stock Python/AdvanceDeclineUnchanged.csv"
AdvanceDeclineUnchanged_df = pd.read_csv(file_path_advance_decline_unchanged, index_col='Unnamed: 0')
last_250_days_data = AdvanceDeclineUnchanged_df.iloc[:, 0:250]
valid_dates = AdvanceDeclineUnchanged_df.loc["Advance", AdvanceDeclineUnchanged_df.loc["Advance"].notna()].index
plot_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': data_feed.index,
    'Advance%': last_250_days_data.loc['Advance%', :].values,
    'Unchanged%': last_250_days_data.loc['Unchanged%', :].values,
    'Decline%': last_250_days_data.loc['Decline%', :].values
})

# Get only valid dates for x-axis
valid_dates = list(map(str, valid_dates))
plot_data = plot_data[plot_data['Date'].isin(valid_dates)]

# Create subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=6, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.04)

# Add traces to subplots
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=data_feed.index, open=data_feed.open, high=data_feed.high, low=data_feed.low, close=data_feed.close), row=1, col=1)

# 52Wks NHNL-Line Chart
_52WksNHNL_line = go.Scatter(x=_52WksNHNL_df.columns[0:249], y=_52WksNHNL_df.iloc[2, 0:250], mode='lines', name='52WksNewHighNewLow', line=dict(color='maroon'))
fig.add_trace(_52WksNHNL_line, row=2, col=1)

# 20Days NHNL-Line Chart
_20DaysNHNL_line = go.Scatter(x=_20DaysNHNL_df.columns[0:250], y=_20DaysNHNL_df.iloc[2, 0:250], mode='lines', name='20DaysNewHighNewLow', line=dict(color='green'))
fig.add_trace(_20DaysNHNL_line, row=3, col=1)

# 4% Gainer Chart
_4percent_line = go.Scatter(x=x_values_4percent, y=y_values_4percent, mode='lines', name='Amount of 4% Gainer', line=dict(color='blue'))
fig.add_trace(_4percent_line, row=4, col=1)

# EMA Breadth Chart
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=_20EMA_Breadth_df.columns[0:250], y=_20EMA_Breadth_df.loc['Percent Above EMA', :].iloc[0:250], mode='lines', name='EMA20', line=dict(color='orange')), row=5, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=_50EMA_Breadth_df.columns[0:250], y=_50EMA_Breadth_df.loc['Percent Above EMA', :].iloc[0:250], mode='lines', name='EMA50', line=dict(color='red')), row=5, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=_200EMA_Breadth_df.columns[0:250], y=_200EMA_Breadth_df.loc['Percent Above EMA', :].iloc[0:250], mode='lines', name='EMA200', line=dict(color='purple')), row=5, col=1)

# Stacked bar chart for Advance Decline Unchanged Chart (Chart 6)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=plot_data['Date'], y=plot_data['Decline%'], name='Decline%', marker_color='red'), row=6, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=plot_data['Date'], y=plot_data['Unchanged%'], name='Unchanged%', marker_color='grey', base=plot_data['Decline%']), row=6, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=plot_data['Date'], y=plot_data['Advance%'], name='Advance%', marker_color='green', base=plot_data['Unchanged%'] + plot_data['Decline%']), row=6, col=1)

# Update layout
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, height=2000, title_text="Thai StockMarket Market Breadth", xaxis=dict(type='category'))
```

[image]

Comment: can you give an example of which dates specifically? also it would be easier to help if we can reproduce the portion of your chart where you are seeing the unexpected behavior. can you copy and paste some of your data into the question? maybe copy the output of `plot_data[plot_data['Date'].between(start_date, end_date)].to_dict()` directly into your question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To exclude market holidays and holidays in time series data, use range breaking. I tested this by taking company stock prices as data similar to your question and making the relevant subplots candlesticks and bars only. The first thing to fix is that the x-axis must be of type `date`. The next step is creating the data for the range destruction. I create contiguous date data based on the dates obtained for the stock price, then compare each to create a list of dates that are only on one side. That is set as the range breaking for the x-axis.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

data_feed = yf.download("AAPL", start="2023-01-01", end="2024-01-01")
data_feed.reset_index(inplace=True)
data_feed['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_feed['Date'])

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

# rangebreaks data
date_all = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2023-01-01','2023-12-29',freq='1d'),'value': np.arange(1,364,1)})
rangebreak_list = pd.merge(data_feed, date_all, on=["Date", "Date"], how ="outer", indicator=True).query(f'_merge != "both"')

# Create subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.05)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=data_feed.Date, open=data_feed.Open, high=data_feed.High, low=data_feed.Low, close=data_feed.Close), row=1, col=1)

# Stacked bar chart for Advance Decline Unchanged Chart (Chart 6)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data_feed['Date'], y=data_feed['Open'], name='Open', marker_color='red'), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data_feed['Date'], y=data_feed['Low'], name='Low', marker_color='grey', base=data_feed['Open']), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data_feed['Date'], y=data_feed['High'], name='High', marker_color='green', base=data_feed['Open'] + data_feed['Low']), row=2, col=1)

# Update layout
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, height=600, title_text="Thai StockMarket Market Breadth", xaxis=dict(type='date'))
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(values=rangebreak_list['Date'].tolist()),
    ]
)
fig.show()
```

[image]